# How to create group indices for nested groups in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple observations nested within individuals. This example dataset includes columns for id and for day of the week (dayweek, 1-7). I have observations from 3 days from each individual. So one individual might have only submitted reports for Sun/Wed/Thu (1, 4, 5), and the other might have submitted reports for Sun/Mon/Tue (1, 2, 3), as in this example:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1:2, each = 6),2),
  dayweek = c(rep(c(1, 4, 5), each = 2),rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 2), 3)
)
```

I want to set up a column that marks each individual's first, second, and third day, like this:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1:2, each = 6),2),
  dayweek = c(rep(c(1, 4, 5), each = 2),rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 2), 3),
  daynum = c(rep(1:3, each = 2, times = 2), 3)
)
```

I tried using

```
df %>% group_indices(id, dayweek)
```

but this produces a new id for each individual-day combination. What's a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if the days were Friday, Saturday, Sunday: then you’d have 6,7,1 but the 6 would be the first day and the 1 would be the third, right? Are the rows already in date order, so that the first row for an id would get daynum = 1?

Comment: Hi, correct: in this case I would like to recode 6 to 1, 7 to 2, and 1 to 3. Yes, the rows are in order but there is a different number of observations for each individual and each day. So they might have 4 observations for Sat, 2 for Sun, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `dplyr`

Using `cumsum` and `!duplicated` with `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(daynum = cumsum(!duplicated(dayweek)))


# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id dayweek daynum
   <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
 1     1       1      1
 2     1       1      1
 3     1       4      2
 4     1       4      2
 5     1       5      3
 6     1       5      3
 7     2       1      1
 8     2       1      1
 9     2       2      2
10     2       2      2
11     2       3      3
12     2       3      3
13     2       3      3
```

#### `tapply` from base `R`

```
unlist(tapply(df$dayweek, df$id, function(x) cumsum(!duplicated(x))))

 1  1  2  2  3  3  1  1  2  2  3  3  3
```

Comment: This handles also the "Friday, Saturday, Sunday" case (`dayweek` 6, 7, 1) well.

Answer (score 4):

We could `group_by` `id` and create an unique `id` for each `dayweek`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(daynum = as.integer(factor(dayweek, levels = unique(dayweek))))

#      id dayweek daynum
#   <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
# 1     1       1      1
# 2     1       1      1
# 3     1       4      2
# 4     1       4      2
# 5     1       5      3
# 6     1       5      3
# 7     2       1      1
# 8     2       1      1
# 9     2       2      2
#10     2       2      2
#11     2       3      3
#12     2       3      3
#13     2       3      3
```

---

In base R we can use `ave` for the same

```
with(df, ave(dayweek, id, FUN = function(x) 
         as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

Comment: For the "Friday, Saturday, Sunday" case (`dayweek` 6, 7, 1), this will return 2, 3, 1 while the OP expects 1, 2, 3 according to the comments.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks, updated the answer to handle that case.

Comment: Interesting to see the use of `unique`. Somehow the `!duplicated` can easily be taken to mean `unique` but applying that becomes tricky.

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, here the OP wanted to follow the correct order based on when the `dayweek` was observed hence, the use of `unique`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779697/how-to-create-group-indices-for-nested-groups-in-r#comment98230839_55779697), the rows are in order.

Then, here are two different approaches which also will handle the "Friday, Saturday, Sunday" case (`dayweek` 6, 7, 1) mentioned in the comments.

1. `rleid()`
2. `fct_inorder()`

#### `rleid()`

This uses the `rleid()` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(daynum2 = data.table::rleid(dayweek))
```

> ```
>       id dayweek daynum daynum2
>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
>  1     1       1      1       1
>  2     1       1      1       1
>  3     1       4      2       2
>  4     1       4      2       2
>  5     1       5      3       3
>  6     1       5      3       3
>  7     2       1      1       1
>  8     2       1      1       1
>  9     2       2      2       2
> 10     2       2      2       2
> 11     2       3      3       3
> 12     2       3      3       3
> 13     2       3      3       3
> 14     3       6      1       1
> 15     3       7      2       2
> 16     3       1      3       3
> ```

Note that an extended data set is used which also covers the "Friday, Saturday, Sunday" case (`dayweek` 6, 7, 1).

#### `fct_inorder()`

This is an enhanced version of [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779765/3817004) which handles also the "Friday, Saturday, Sunday" case. It uses the `fct_inorder()` from the `forcats` package which reorders factor levels by first appearance.

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(daynum2 = 
           dayweek %>% 
           as.character() %>% 
           forcats::fct_inorder() %>% 
           as.integer()
         )
```

The output is the same as above.

#### Data

This is an extended data set which includes also the "Friday, Saturday, Sunday" case (`dayweek` 6, 7, 1):

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1:2, each = 6), 2, rep(3, 3)),
  dayweek = c(rep(c(1, 4, 5), each = 2),rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 2), 3, 6, 7, 1),
  daynum = c(rep(1:3, each = 2, times = 2), 3, 1:3)
)
```